# Select rows from table by id of a left join table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables:

```
+-------------+    +-------------+    +-------------+
|    hotel    |    |   hot_cat   |    |   category  |
+------+------+    +------+------+    +-------------+
|  id  | name |    |  hid |  cid |    |  id  | name |
+------+------+    +------+------+    +-------------+
|   1  |   X  |    |   1  |   1  |    |   1  | cat1 |
+------+------+    +------+------+    +-------------+
|   2  |   Y  |    |   1  |   2  |    |   2  | cat2 |
+------+------+    +------+------+    +-------------+
|   3  |   Z  |    |   2  |   2  |    |   3  | cat3 |
+------+------+    +------+------+    +-------------+
                   |   2  |   3  |    |   4  | cat4 |
                   +------+------+    +-------------+
                   |   2  |   4  |
                   +------+------+
```

I want to select hotels where category is some value, but with all other categories assigned to this hotel. I have this query:

```
SELECT hot.*,GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR '<br>') AS cats
FROM hotel hot
LEFT JOIN hot_cat hc ON hc.hid = hot.id
LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id = hc.cid
WHERE cat.id = 2
GROUP BY hot.id
```

So I get this:

```
+------+------+-------------------------+
|  id  | name |           cats          |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   1  |   X  |          'cat2'         |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   2  |   Y  |          'cat2'         |
+------+------+-------------------------+
```

What I want to achieve:

```
+------+------+-------------------------+
|  id  | name |           cats          |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   1  |   X  |      'cat1<br>cat2'     |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   2  |   Y  |  'cat2<br>cat3<br>cat4' |
+------+------+-------------------------+
```

I also want it to work without the where clause and get hotels without category assigned:

```
+------+------+-------------------------+
|  id  | name |           cats          |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   1  |   X  |      'cat1<br>cat2'     |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   2  |   Y  |  'cat2<br>cat3<br>cat4' |
+------+------+-------------------------+
|   3  |   Z  |           ''            |
+------+------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your query at the `hot_cat` table, and then join into `hotel`. It's one extra jump through the tables, but it solves the problem.

```
SELECT hot.*,GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR '<br>') AS cats
FROM hot_cat hc1
LEFT JOIN hotel hot ON hc1.hid = hot.id
LEFT JOIN hot_cat hc ON hc.hid = hot.id
LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id = hc.cid
WHERE hc1.id = 2
GROUP BY hot.id
```

If, instead, you don't need the WHERE then you can just use your existing query without the WHERE clause.